# Where does cuda-repo-cross-<identifier>-all.deb come from?

Tags: cuda, jetson-xavier

I am trying to set up a cross-compile environment on an AWS EC2 Ubuntu box targeting Nvida Xavier devices on Cuda 10.2. I tried following the "instructions" at https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/10.2/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#cross-platform which say to install

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-cross-<identifier>_all.deb
```

but no clue as to where I might get hold of that .deb file, or what `<identifier>` should be replaced with. I have installed the native package cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-10-2-local-10.2.89-440.33.01_1.0-1_amd64.deb and there are a load of .deb files in /var/cuda-repo-10-2-local-10.2.89-440.33.01, but none of them are that one.

Comment: [this](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-sdk-manager) is probably a better starting point.  Also see [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/sdk-manager/install-with-sdkm-jetson/index.html)

Comment: Alternatively, I typed "cuda-repo-cross download" into google and got [this link](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/cross-linux-sbsa/) as the first hit, which is exactly what you are looking for, if I understood your question correctly

Comment: @talonmies, if only it was that simple. The Xavier isn't SBSA and we need 10.2 not 11

Comment: There are similar repos for other Ubuntu versions but none offering aarch64 at v10

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out that the instructions that can be found by googling for, for instance, "cuda install cross compile" are wrong, or at least so incomplete as makes no difference.

Instead, use the SDK manager https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-sdk-manager to install just the host tools. It does run without a GUI.